# JNI Set<Primitive>ArrayRegion "start" argument refers to which pointer?

Tags: arrays, java-native-interface, primitive

Typically when I'm moving arrays in and out of JNI, I'll just copy the whole thing to and from its native counterpart, but I've encountered a situation where I need just a piece of one going to the other.
When in Java land, you've got `System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)`. Super intuitive. But in JNI, you've just got `env->Set<Primitive>ArrayRegion(array, start, length, buf)`. After much googling and reading several JNI references, all I get are those argument names.

Question is, does `start` refer to `srcPos` or `destPos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some quick experimenting yields that the answer is `destPos`. You're declaring where in the Java array you'd like to begin copying. If you want a particular subsection of `src`, you'll have to do some pointer arithmetic to position `srcPos` where you'd like.